# AttributeError: module 'openpyxl.cell' has no attribute 'get_column_letter'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

when I try to run code regarding retrieving column letter from a number I keep getting the following error:

> AttributeError: module 'openpyxl.cell' has no attribute 'get_column_letter'

This is the code I am trying to run:

```
print(openpyxl.cell.get_column_letter(26))
```

I expect this to run with no error.

Answer (score 1):

Because this attribute has been moved to utils within this module, the way to call this without getting an error is to call it from its new location:

```
print(openpyxl.utils.cell.get_column_letter(26))
```

This should be working now.